# Copying an item rather than moving in the knockout sortable seating chart example

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

This is the seating chart example of knockout sortable: http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/
Based on the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966923/knockout-draggable-sortable-mapping-clone-alteration) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677534/knockout-sortable-drag-and-drop-from-outside), I tried to change the seating chart example such that the items from available students copied rather than moved as in the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/786/)

The changes are shown below :

```
......
......
<div class="seats" data-bind="sortable: { data: students, allowDrop: $root.isTableFull, dragged: handleDraggedItem }">
......
......
<div class="new" data-bind="sortable: availableStudents">
        <div class="student available" data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </div>
.......
.......
Student.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new Student(this.id,this.name(),this.gender);
};
.......
.......
this.handleDraggedItem = function(item, event, ui) {
        console.log("handleDraggedItem");
        **return new Student(0,ui.item.text(),'');**
    };
.......
.......
$(".available").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".seats",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ko.utils.domData.set(event.target, "ko_dragItem", true);
    }
});
```

The code that I'm unable to solve is the handledraggeditem [return new Student(0,ui.item.text(),'')]. How can I get the other values (id and gender) except name(this I'm able to get from text) such that I can send them here..

Due to this the $data for the dragged items have 0 as id and '' as gender as below..

```
{
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Kylie",
          "gender": "female",
          "group": "griffindor"
        },
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Angel",
          "gender": "",
          "group": ""
        }
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user starts to drag an element, you are currently attaching a value of `true` to it:

```
$(".available").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".seats",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ko.utils.domData.set(event.target, "ko_dragItem", true); // <---
    }
});
```

Whatever data you attach there is what the `dragged:` callback will receive as its first argument — in your case, `handleDraggedItem`:

```
this.handleDraggedItem = function(item, event, ui) {
  // 'item' is now 'true'
  console.log("handleDraggedItem");
};
```

If you instead look up the `Student` that is bound to the dragged element with `ko.dataFor` and attach that:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
  var student = ko.dataFor(event.target);

  ko.utils.domData.set(event.target, "ko_dragItem", student);
}
```

your `handleDraggedItem` handler will receive that `Student` as its first argument, and you can call your `Student.prototype.clone` method on it:

```
this.handleDraggedItem = function(item, event, ui) {
  return item.clone();
};
```

Comment: its copying the first time u shift an element but moving the next time, any ideas why?? .http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/795/ --Tx

Comment: the issue is solved when I comment out updateLastAction, 'arg.sourceparent' is coming undefined.. any ideas why?? Tx